# Is there a way to know if the user is on a particular heading, paragraph or a div etc

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I was trying to find a way to start an animation only if the user is on it, at first I tried getting screen size, and its works, but its not an optimal solution.
Once I was googling I found something where we could get ID (by the ID tag) while scrolling, if somehow I could get the ID while scrolling down, I could use a simple JavaScript function to play the animation.
is there any way?

Comment: What do you mean by "*on* a particular..."? Would that element be in focus? What if there are multiple items on the screen simultaneously?

Comment: @user1599011 on a particular means, I have a website have heading on top of each animated function, all headers, paragraphs would be in focus, at each time when the user scroll, function call get where the user is at and play that "particular" function. In simple: at each scroll function starts line by line from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found that by my own.
What I was trying to do? I wanted to start an animation (skills bar) only when the user is seeing it/on it/have passed previous information.
I did this by using section, JavaScript and then trigger the animation when user is on it.

AN EXAMPLE (Im sorry for messy code, I dont know to align code here)

```
 <section id="name">
        <div class="hello">
<h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
    </section>
    
        <section id="aboutMe">
        <div class="hello">
<h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
    </section>
    
        <section id="skills">
        <div class="hello">
             <h1>these are my skills</h1>
</div>
    </section>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
     var element = document.querySelector("#skills");
    
    function isInViewPort(element) {
    // Get the bounding client rectangle position in the viewport
    var bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Checking part. Here the code checks if it's *fully* visible
    // Edit this part if you just want a partial visibility
    if (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

    var element = document.querySelector("#skills");
    
    if (isInViewPort(element)) {
        alert('true')
    }
```

hope this will help someone in the future